# Get users who did not login to exchange server for the past 120 days using powershell script in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have an web application that needs to connect to Exchange server and get list of users who did not login to the mailbox in the last 120 days.

This needs to be done using powershell script in C#. 
The code uses powershell script to find the users who have not logged in to exchange server in 120 days. When trying to use the script mentioned in the code it returns count as 0 but there are many users who have not logged in the past 120 days.

Below the current code.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

using System.Security;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace Exchange
{
    public partial class NoLoginLast120Days : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string serverAddress = "my server address", runasPassword = "serverpassword", runasUsername = "server username";

            // Prepare the credentials that will be used when connecting
            // to the server. More info on the user to use on the notes
            // below this code snippet.
            SecureString ssRunasPassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char x in runasPassword)
                ssRunasPassword.AppendChar(x);
            PSCredential credentials = new PSCredential(runasUsername, ssRunasPassword);

            // Prepare the connection
            var connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
                new Uri("https://" + serverAddress + "/PowerShell"),
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
                credentials);
            connInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
            connInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
            connInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;

            // Create the runspace where the command will be executed
            var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connInfo);
            runspace.Open();

            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            Command getStatistics = new Command("Get-MailboxStatistics");

            getStatistics.Parameters.Add("Filter", "$_.Lastlogontime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-1000)");            
            ps.Commands.Add(getStatistics);

            Collection<PSObject> commandResults = ps.Invoke();


            runspace.Close();
            runspace.Dispose();
        }        
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I tried getStatistics.Parameters.Add("Filter", "Lastlogontime $null");         for getting results which had lastlogontime as null, it was successful.
I was able to process the commandResults.

I even tried the below for getting users with lastlogontime as not null, so I can filter the desired results using C# but it did not work out.

getStatistics.Parameters.Add("Filter", "Lastlogontime -ne $null");

Also the users count is huge that I get System.OutOfMemoryException if I try without any filters.

If there is a way to get users who have not logged in for the past 120 days using powershell script in C# it will be really helpful as I am stuck with this for a long time.

**Update**
Below code works in powershell. It will be really helpful to know how to use this in C#.

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Server <servername> | where {$_.LastLogonTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-120)} | ft displayName, lastlogontime
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working? Stack Overflow is for questions to assist you, not to have code written for you.

Comment: getStatistics.Parameters.Add("Filter", "$_.Lastlogontime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-1000)"); As explained in my description, this script does not return desired results. I am new to powershell in C#. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you test you command in exchange shell itself? I think it should throw a invalid argument exception.

Comment: @OlafReitz.. yes while testing the command in powershell it threw "get-date is not recognized as cmdlet" error.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your environment its not easy to answer. But I think the issue is a miss understanding from the timestamps you are using. So before you can use it, you need to understand the difference between Last-Logon-Timestamp and Last-Logon AD attribute:

[Last-Logon-Timestamp Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676824(VS.85).aspx)

This is the time that the user last logged into the domain. Whenever a user logs on, the value of this attribute is read from the DC. If the value is older [ current_time - msDS-LogonTimeSyncInterval ], the value is updated. The initial update after the raise of the domain functional level is calculated as 14 days minus random percentage of 5 days. So with the default settings in place the lastLogontimeStamp will be 9-14 days behind the current date (as mentioned by Microsoft [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works/)).

[Last-Logon Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676823(VS.85).aspx)

The last time the user logged on. This value is stored as a large integer that represents the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). A value of zero means that the last logon time is unknown. This attribute is not replicated and is maintained separately on each domain controller in the domain. To get an accurate value for the user's last logon in the domain, the Last-Logon attribute for the user must be retrieved from every domain controller in the domain. Keep noted that your "solution" might pick different domain controller here and therefore will get different results!

This should explain your issue and why you see some "strange" results as using the Last-Logon-Timestamp is more a random value ...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am clear with the differences now. I tried getStatistics.Parameters.Add("Filter", "Lastlogontime $null");         for getting results which had lastlogontime as null, it was successful. I got the long integer and then converted it to proper date time, But my requirement now is to get a working script which will bring results of users who have not logged into mailbox.